# Validating AdobeTarget’s action response (based on Target business rules) against white-list of valid action responses

Tags: adobe, multivariate-testing

I can't find any information on the web about this so I thought I 'd try here!  What we want to do is validate Target’s action response (based on Target business rules) against a white-list of valid action responses. If Adobe Target’s action response call is valid then it should be used to present experience/content to user. If the Adobe Target’s action response call is invalid then user should be presented with the default content. The default content is not driven by Adobe Target. I understand in theory that there is a client-side and server-side approach to this but wondering if anyone has any experience/insight into this and could point me to any documentation that might help me? We are leaning towards the server side solution. We understand that we'll need to create some type of service that captures/stores/validates the checksums of the response but looking for more details.

Thanks!

Comment: I did figure out where the response was being read and I'm leveraging the existing promises within the native code instead of duplicating code.